# How to break from playwright page.expect_download()?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Is there some way to "break" from `playwright` `page.expect_download()` waiting for download?

Like if I want to stop current download without crashing everything by pressing button in my gui.

My code is:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from time import sleep


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with (sync_playwright() as pw):
        browser = pw.chromium.launch_persistent_context(
            r'D:\the_profile', headless=False
        )
        the_page = browser.pages[0]

        the_page.goto(url)

        with the_page.expect_download(timeout=21600000) as download_info:
            the_page.click("#dl-button")
            # Maybe I can add something here that can handle command to break page.expect_download from main thread?

        download = download_info.value
        download.save_as("D:\\" + download.suggested_filename)
```

It... erm... Looks like it works as it is designed to.

I waits for file to be downloaded, then it saves it to folder.

But I can't find any way to interfere into that waiting if I want to.

Using timeout is not a variant. Maybe I will need to break after 10-15 seconds, maybe I will need to download file that will be downloaded for half of an hour (yes, the site gives me slow speed on downloading files).

Update 1:
Hmm... Let me try sending waiter to separate thread...

Update 2:
Playwright crashes when trying to multithread it...
And setting things like it is all in there and setting all things I want to work in that way... way it is possible, but...

Update 3:
Halfly bypassed on my current project by starting `expect_download()` only when 95% of file are already downloaded. In my situation I can do that. But there can be predictable problem with small file that will finish download before my code starts `expect`.

Comment: I think it may need to run code in separated thread and kill this thread when you press button.

Comment: @ggorlen But yes, thinking on it, setting it to 6 or 12 hours sounds not bad idea. Fixed things in post.

Comment: Yeah, the breaking is a good question and unrelated to the timeout, which is just a general "best practice" regardless of breaking or not. Thanks for the update.